Twillo RestAPI Nuget not compliant
The last Twillo Nuget show me on Visual Studio 2022, that not .NET compliant for Windows 11:
"NU1701: Das Paket "Twilio 7.3.1" wurde nicht mit dem Projektzielframework "UAP,Version=v10.0.16299", sondern mit ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" wiederhergestellt. Dieses Paket ist mit Ihrem Projekt möglicherweise nicht vollständig kompatibel."
English Traslation

"NU1701: The package "Twilio 7.3.1" was not restored with the project target framework "UAP,Version=v10.0.16299" but with ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1". This package may not be fully compatible with your project ."

Any solution for that?
Twillo 7.3.1 is based on .NET 4 and Microsoft last .NET is version 8. So i think, Twillo self must fix it?

Are you using a UWP project in visual studio?
If yes, go to project properties and change the minimum and target version 10.0.16299 of the Windows 11 operating system.
The doc says,

When creating a UWP app in Microsoft Visual Studio, you can choose which version to target. Projects using .NET Standard 2.0 must have a Minimum Version of Build 16299 or later.

Docs Referred:
NuGet Warning NU1701
Choose a UWP version
